# Break in GDB when program counter is certain value

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I am attempting to debug a segmentation fault using GDB (on Windows 10 using the Qt toolchain).  I know that the segmentation fault occurs because the program counter gets set to 0x30 (obviously an invalid instruction address).  However, by the time I get notified that a segmentation fault has occurred, I am already in invalid memory space and have no way to backtrace the function calls that got me to that point.

For example, this is the output of `backtrace` after the segmentation fault is detected:

```
#0  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Is there a way to instruction GDB to break immediately when the PC is set to a certain value but before the next instruction is executed?

I tried `break *0x30` but this didn't accomplish what I want.

Or perhaps, is there a different way to debug this type of segmentation fault?

Comment: This looks similar to [gdb bug 30255](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30255), but the fix is not yet in any release.

Comment: If your platform supports it, [reverse execution](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html), part of [process record and replay](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html#Process-Record-and-Replay), may help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to instruction GDB to break immediately when the PC is set to a certain value

No.

Implementing such a feature would require single-stepping the program, which is too slow for any practical program.